# Ubuntu 13.10 install php-fpm with apache 2.4

Tags: apache2, php, webserver, cgi

I tried multiple tutorials on how to install php-fpm (cgi) with apache2. None of them worked with 13.10. I even installed ubuntu completly new after each one. This is one for example:
[How to configure Apache to run PHP as FastCGI on Ubuntu 12.04 via terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/378734/how-to-configure-apache-to-run-php-as-fastcgi-on-ubuntu-12-04-via-terminal)
https://alexcabal.com/installing-apache-mod_fastcgi-php-fpm-on-ubuntu-server-maverick/

Are they too outdated ? I mean I looked for over 2 hours for one for ubuntu +13.

It would be nice if you know one that works or could explain it. I mean there is not much I could have done wrong, as it is mostly copy and paste. Everything worked great, but when I check phpinfo() it still shows apache2 as server api.